# Unit testing and Integration testing

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, express, testing, mocha.js

i'm currently developping a nodejs/express rest api (personal project), and i wanted to learn as much as i ca from this project.

So in my project i'm using `sequelize` as an `ORM` layer, i have a model named `bus, and i have build CRUD endpoint to this model.

now i want to do some test this model/api i have developped, i read some tutorial about testing and found that there are multiple type of testing seperated in two big categories : white-box vs black-box.

So i have written some integration tests that test my api(integration test are black-box testing)

and i want right know to write some unit-testing, but i don't know what to test, the `bus` model is a Sequelize model, so everything that i would test would be already tested in the `sequelize` library it self. and testing the api endpoints is done via integration tests.

PS: its my first time writing tests.

i'm using the following technologies :  `nodejs`, `sequelize`, `express`, `mocha`, `chai`.

**Bus Model Definition**

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

module.exports = function(sequelize) {

    let Bus =  sequelize.define('bus', {
        name: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
        },
    });


    Bus.associate = function(models) {
        Bus.hasOne(models.LaneBus, {
            foreignKey: 'busId'
        });
    };

    return Bus;
}
```

**Bus Api endpoint testings**

```
const request = require('superagent');
const expect = require('chai').expect;

const app = require('../../src/app');
var http = require('http');

const models = require('../../src/models');


describe("bus", function () {

    var bus_id;

    it('should create bus', function (done) {

        request.post('http://localhost:3000/bus')
            .type('form')
            .send({
                name: 'bus_test_1',
            }).set('Accept', 'application/json')
            .set('Authorization', global.JWT_TOKEN_TEST_ADMIN)
            .end((err, res) => {
                expect(res.status).to.be.eq(201, 'invalid return code');
                expect(res.body.status).to.be.eq('success', 'invalid retun status');

                bus_id = res.body.id;

                done();
            })
    });

    it('should get list of bus', function (done) {

        request.get('http://localhost:3000/bus')
            .set('Accept', 'application/json')
            .end((err, res) => {
                expect(res.status).to.be.eq(200, 'invalid return code');
                expect(res.body.metadata).to.not.be.undefined

                done();
            })
    });


    it('should modify bus', function (done) {

        request.put(`http://localhost:3000/bus/${bus_id}`)
            .type('form')
            .send({
                name: 'bus_test_2'
            })
            .set('Authorization', global.JWT_TOKEN_TEST_ADMIN)
            .end((err, res) => {
                expect(res.status).to.be.eq(200, 'invalid return code');
                expect(res.body.status).to.be.eq('success', 'invalid retun status');
                done();
            });
    });

    it('modify bus should get error because bus dont exists', function (done) {

        request.put(`http://localhost:3000/bus/aaa`)
            .type('form')
            .send({
                name: 'bus_test_2'
            })
            .set('Authorization', global.JWT_TOKEN_TEST_ADMIN)
            .end((err, res) => {
                expect(res.status).to.be.eq(404, 'invalid return code');
                expect(res.body.status).to.be.eq('failure', 'invalid return code');
                done();
            });
    });


    it('should get bus', function (done) {

        request.get(`http://localhost:3000/bus/${bus_id}`)
            .end((err, res) => {
                expect(res.status).to.be.eq(200, 'invalid return code');
                expect(res.body.name).to.be.eq('bus_test_2');
                done();
            });
    });

    it('get bus should return error because bus dont exist', function (done) {

        request.get(`http://localhost:3000/bus/aaaa`)
            .end((err, res) => {
                expect(res.status).to.be.eq(404, 'invalid return code');
                expect(res.body.status).to.be.eq('failure', 'invalid return code');
                done();
            });
    });



    it('user role cannot create bus', function (done) {
        request.post('http://localhost:3000/bus')
            .type('form')
            .send({
                name: 'bus_test_1',
            }).set('Accept', 'application/json')
            .set('Authorization', global.JWT_TOKEN_TEST_USER)
            .end((err, res) => {
                expect(res.body.status).to.be.eq('failure', 'invalid retun status');


                done();
            })
    })

    it('user role cannot modify bus', function (done) {
        request.put(`http://localhost:3000/bus/${bus_id}`)
            .type('form')
            .send({
                name: 'bus_test_2'
            })
            .set('Authorization', global.JWT_TOKEN_TEST_USER)
            .end((err, res) => {
                expect(res.body.status).to.be.eq('failure', 'invalid retun status');
                done();
            });
    })


    it('user role cannot delete bus', function (done) {
        request.delete(`http://localhost:3000/bus/${bus_id}`)
            .set('Authorization', global.JWT_TOKEN_TEST_USER)
            .end((err, res) => {
                expect(res.body.status).to.be.eq('failure', 'invalid return code');
                done();
            });
    })


    it('should delete bus', function (done) {

        request.delete(`http://localhost:3000/bus/${bus_id}`)
            .set('Authorization', global.JWT_TOKEN_TEST_ADMIN)
            .end((err, res) => {
                expect(res.status).to.be.eq(200, 'invalid return code');
                done();
            });
    });

    it('delete bus should get error because bus dont exist', function (done) {

        request.delete(`http://localhost:3000/bus/${bus_id}`)
            .set('Authorization', global.JWT_TOKEN_TEST_ADMIN)
            .end((err, res) => {
                expect(res.status).to.be.eq(404, 'invalid return code');
                expect(res.body.status).to.be.eq('failure', 'invalid return code');
                done();
            });
    });





});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unclear requirement/exceptions make code difficult to test. Sometimes, you just don't know what could break your code. This happens all the time in the real world. You don't know what could break your code; otherwise, you fixed it.

In any situation, I recommend to test with code coverage, such as [Istanbul](https://www.npmjs.com/package/istanbul). Make sure your code is at least 80% tested. Later on when you updated the code or fixed a bug, you can see what is not being tested, and add the corresponded test.

Comment: that what i did :), i want to know a simple thing, if some function/operation to test database connection or some complex dependency, it better to use integration test to test it right? unit test is used for simple function

Comment: Ideally, passed unit test and then start integration test. In a large project, when requirement and design are solid (which takes time), functions are direct and testable, unit test should be required. 1) unit test is about the app; 2) integration test is about the system; 3) in comparison, integration test costs more time and resources. Your saying here is unit testing with real database connection. As we rushing to release project, it is more and more common. Many CI are supporting it. However, if possible, I still recommend to follow the textbook. It is about quality and attitude.

Answer (score 1):

1. Integration (black box) test: I would recommend [CucumberJS](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js) for
   integration tests as it provides a plain language for defining your features and can test end-to-end features, not just API endpoints. For example:

   ```
   Feature: Simple maths
    In order to do maths
    As a developer
    I want to increment variables
   ```
2. White box unit tests: Mocha & Chai are good so you can continue with those, but I would add [Sinon](http://sinonjs.org/) for stubs and mocks. So the tests that you have above can be turned into integration tests (think something like [Yakbak](https://github.com/flickr/yakbak)) or go the other way and turn them into unit tests with Sinon.

These are my suggestions but feel free to look around and pick your favourite library for tests. Just make sure you make the distinction between integration and unit tests.